# The message "User was removed" can be ambiguous

Tags: discussion

You could save me a few heart attacks :-) by changing the message to the more clearer "Voter was removed" (or whatever you see fitting). I first thought I was removed (maybe on another suboverflow, what do I know).

Comment: Seems sensible.  If the response here is positive, why not post this to the big meta forum for all of stackexchange?

Comment: Isn’t there an explanatory link ([learn more](https://mathoverflow.net/help/user-was-removed)) right after the message? *This* was in fact the result of a discussion of this issue on the site-wide meta here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130122/more-descriptive-user-was-removed-explanation .

Comment: If you'd wake up, and a voice would tell you "The person is dead", would you also freak out that you have died?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would definitely freak out, if not for the stated reason.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with HaukeReddmann that, when I saw the message, I thought the same thing (that I had been removed).  As to @AsafKaragila's question, I think that the more relevant comment would be waking up and hearing "Human has been killed", at which point, yes, I might fear for my life.

Comment: How about *votes* were removed, since a user being deleted has no relation to votes being removed for reasons such as too much voting.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that this feature request is marked (meta-tag:status-completed): [More descriptive “User was removed” explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130122).

Comment: @LSpice: There is a difference between "fearing for your life" and thinking that *you* are the one who is dead.

Comment: The stackoverflow difference is that you have more than one "life". (I used to be downvoted to hell on the programming suboverflow, for what reasons ever, and thus thought it was a realistic possibility to get booted *there*. Frankly, I don't even know if that is possible at all, or if my account counts global for all subs.)

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this message. Had it been "User has been taken care of", or "Soul has been reaped", I would have found it sinister, but the current version is just fine.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: [Not in the achievements dropdown, there isn't.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcSTm.png)